# MySQL - how to set one column data via other unique column

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table

I have a MySQL table with 3 columns:
`title` | `element_id` | `id`

`id` has been auto_incremented as an int.

I want to increment `element_id` based on the description of `title`, such that if the value of `title` is unique, in the order of `id`, the `element_id` will increase from 1 to ...

Example of how table should look:

```
title, element_id, id
Baker, 1, 1
Baker, 2, 2
Plumber, 1, 3
Plumber, 2, 4
Plumber, 3, 5
Doctor, 1, 6
```

I have found stack posts on how to do this when you know the name of the title, such as doing something like

```
UPDATE table_name SET element_ID = 1 
WHERE title = 'Baker';
```

But in this case there is not auto incrementation, and we have to know the name of the `title` in order to change the table. But how could this be done with ANY `title` name?

Additionally - to make this problem easier perhaps, all the `titles` are organized together in the table (ie no mixing of `titles` like below)

```
title, element_id, id
Baker, 1, 1
Plumber, 1, 2
Baker, 2, 3
Plumber, 2, 4
Plumber, 3, 5
Doctor, 1, 6
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions:

```
update table_name t join
       (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by title order by id) as seqnum
        from t
       ) tt
       on tt.id = t.id
    set t.element_id = tt.seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without window functions:

```
update tablename t inner join (
  select t.*, 
    (select count(*) from tablename
    where title = t.title and id < t.id) counter 
  from tablename t   
) c on c.title = t.title and c.id = t.id
set t.element_id = c.counter + 1;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dCXhsmzw4Kb1j8ccJRwnGP/0).
Results:

```
| title   | element_id | id  |
| ------- | ---------- | --- |
| Baker   | 1          | 1   |
| Baker   | 2          | 2   |
| Plumber | 1          | 3   |
| Plumber | 2          | 4   |
| Plumber | 3          | 5   |
| Doctor  | 1          | 6   |
```

Comment: Thanks for you help -  I get an error when I try to perform this : Query 1 ERROR: You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause. Do I have to create a new table 'c' first before running this? I think this is the case because you have used the inner join command - I guess that is what you were perhaps showing in your demo?

Comment: As you can see in the demo the code works without error, so you must have used it incorrectly.

Comment: Could you please explain where this c variable comes from in your query?

Comment: `c` is the alias of the query that is joined to the table.